# How much space on the hard drive do I need to upgrade to Active Directory 2003?

Tags: active-directory, windows-2000

On my forest root, is there a certain amount of space I need to upgrade to 2003 Active Directory?  I know I need to put in the cd/dvd for 2003 and do adprep, so I'm guess lots of space is used.  The disk is almost full now so if it is too much, I don't know how I can ever upgrade.

This is not an upgrade of the Windows 2000 OS, just an upgrade to Windows 2003 AD.  Another machine will eventually take the place of the forest root, but I have to prep things, as I understand it, before I can pass the FSMO roles to the new machine and remove the old machine.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Are you talking about raising the Forest Functional Level? If so, that doesn't require running `adprep`

Comment: @MDMarra I thought you had to prep the AD before you can raise it to 2003 functionality?  Maybe it is forest prep?

Comment: @MDMarra, I think he is just talking about updating the schema, so he can add a newer DC.

Comment: johnny, do you want to install a 2003 DC along side your 2000 DC, or do you already have an existing 2003 DC and want to raise the functional level from 2000 to 2003?

Comment: I don't have exact numbers, but I would to take a look at the size of your `C:\Winnt\NTDS`, and see how big that is.  If you have enough free space, for ~2 * ( the current size of C:\Winnt\NTDS) I bet you will probably be ok.

Comment: @MDMarra I have an old forest root.  I have a new machine to replace it.  The new machine is 2003.  To do that, I thought, you have to put the 2003 server media into the 2000 machine that is the forest root.  Prep the AD, transfer roles.

Comment: Right. You do. It's unclear what your current and what your proposed infrastructures are. Why would you even want to install 2003 now, it goes end of support in just over a year. Why not 2008 R2 or later? Also, how much space *exactly* do you have on the existing DC?

Comment: As MDMarra suggests, you're approaching this wrong.  Rather than going through all this effort to upgrade to a decade-old AD level, you should probably jump to 2008R2 instead.

Comment: @MDMarra I thought you had to go to 2003 first then 2008.  Not much space, measure in MB, maybe 300 at most.

Comment: @HopelessN00b That is my plan.

Comment: @johnny You can absolutely install a 2008 R2 into a Windows 2000 Native FFL and DFL domain. No need to go to 2003 at all. See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/understanding-active-directory-functional-levels(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 2):

300MB is plenty of space for the required Schema updates needed to introduce a later domain controller into the forest.